# discord.py on_message stops working after disowning linux job & disconnecting

Tags: python, linux, discord.py

I'm writing a discord-bot in python and it runs alright from IntelliJ and even from Terminal.

The problem starts when i try to let it run on a linux server while not beeing connected to it

```py
    # Called when a message is created and sent to a server.
    # Parameters:   message – A Message of the current message.
    async def on_message(self, message):
        print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
        try:
            await self.serverLog.on_message(message)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(e)
        try:
            await self.werwolfBot.on_message(message)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(e)
```

i start the bot via commandline

```sh
cd WerwolfBot
python3.6 -m werwolf &
disown
```

while still connected via putty on_message and all other events do trigger

and when i disconnect the ssh connection to the linux server
from that moment on it will trigger other events like on_voice_state_update but not on_message

I expected that i can let the bot run disowned and it will still work. But it only works for other events than on_message

Comment: Your problem might be that your code is not formatted for Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer on Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148698) about what `disown` actually does. Here's the part relevant to your question:

> However note that it still is connected to the terminal, so if the terminal is destroyed (which can happen if it was a pty, like those created by xterm or ssh, and the controlling program is terminated, by closing the xterm or terminating the SSH connection), the program will fail as soon as it tries to read from standard input or write to standard output.

So your `on_message` fails as soon as the `print` tries to write to `stdout`.

I can think of a couple of solutions you could try:

1. Use `nohup` instead (this is the most turnkey solution)
2. Redirect `stdout` (and maybe `stderr`) to some other file
3. `print` to someplace other that `stdout` by passing a `file=` argument
4. Use `logging` to handle your logs and don't print them to `stdout` (See [Setting Up Logging](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging.html#logging-setup))